# Read sharepoint field list using CSOM in powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I have created 2 column in sharepoint list. One field called owner is person or group type column and the other one is website template using choice type column.

The question how to read the value owner and website template column above.

Here is the code so far:

```
listName ="CustomerList" 

Add-Type -Path "D:\libs\Powershell Office365\Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "D:\libs\Powershell Office365\Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "D:\libs\Powershell Office365\Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll" 

# connect/authenticate to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object.. 
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials 



if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value) 
{ 
    Write-Host "Connected to SharePoint Online site: '$Url'" -ForegroundColor Red 
} 

$web = $clientContext.Web
$clientContext.load($web)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$list = $clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)

$camlQuery = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery;
$camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View>
<Query>
 <Where> 
      <Eq>   
       <FieldRef Name='Status' /> 
            <Value Type='Text'>Approve</Value>
         </Eq>
       </Where>
 </Query>
</View>"

$items = $list.GetItems( $camlQuery )
$clientContext.Load($list)
$clientContext.Load($items) 
#execute query 
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Write-Host "Connecting to SharePoint Online, URL = $rootUrl"
try
{
   Connect-SPOService -Url $rootUrl -Credential $credential
   Write-Host "Successfully connected.." -ForegroundColor Green
}
catch
{
   Write-Error "Failed to connect to $url - check the credentials and URL!" $_
}

foreach($item in $items)
{
    $siteUrl  = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/"
    $title = $item["Title"]
    $owner = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue]
    $owner = $item["Owner"]
    $siteTemplate =  $item.GetFormattedValue("Website Template")


    Write-host $title, $status, $owner, $siteTemplate


}
Disconnect-SPOService
```

Based on the code above, i unable to display Website Template and Owner column. Any feedbacks or help greatly appreciate.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get person type field value:

```
$owner = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue($item["Owner"]).LookupValue
```

The choice value should work using `$item.GetFormattedValue("Website Template")`. Make sure the field name is correct.